# jquery find in container ,the closest element by attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a problem to find the closest element.

```
var el = $("#" + this.tableId + "_editorForm").find('[name=' + o.name + ']');
```

Works ok, but when i want the closest element of 'el' with

```
$("#" + this.tableId + "_editorForm").find("[dependent-level=" + parseInt(el.attr('dependent-level') - 1) + "]");
```

it returns the first match in the form and not the closest element of 'el'.
I need the closest element of 'el' in form with the matching dependent-level attribute.
Thanks

Comment: Please share html as well

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/L1fqzgqs/